# Mysql update null values with value got by comparing another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a table "users" as below:

```
id, add_id, add
1, 1, abc
2, null, abc
3, null, xyz
4, 2, xyz
```

Expected output:

```
id, add_id, add
1, 1, abc
2, 1, abc
3, 2, xyz
4, 2, xyz
```

Please suggest a MySQL query to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method uses window functions:

```
select id, max(add_id) over (partition by add), add
from t;
```

If you want to change the value, then the update would be:

```
update t join
       (select add, max(add_id) as add_id
        from t
        group by add
       ) tt
       on t.add = tt.add
    set t.add_id = tt.add_id
    where t.add_id is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the id From the table.

if you have more than 1 row with and aff_id and add,  then you must LIMIT the inner SELECT

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `add_id` VARCHAR(4),
>   `add` VARCHAR(3)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `add_id`, `add`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', 'abc'),
>   ('2', null, 'abc'),
>   ('3', null, 'xyz'),
>   ('4', '2', 'xyz');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1 t2 
> SET `add_id` = (SELECT `add_id` FROM (SELECT * FROM table1) t1 WHERE t1. `add` = t2.`add` AND `add_id` IS NOT NULL) 
> WHERE `add_id` IS NULL
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | add_id | add
> -: | :----- | :--
>  1 | 1      | abc
>  2 | 1      | abc
>  3 | 2      | xyz
>  4 | 2      | xyz
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48770793f6e1434745aff136dedfa71c)*

Comment: t2 is the alias of the updated table, as you use the same table for updateing and getting the information, you must use aliases, so that mysql can differentiate them